# Confusion matrix - variables with inconsistent numbers

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am working on image classification with CNN and want to check my model with confusion matrix and class report from Sklearn.

**Dataset structure:**

```
/
|   /data_split
|   |_train
|   |   /dog           
|   |   dog1.jpg
|   |   dog2.jpg
|   |       …….
|   |   /cat           
|   |   cat1.jpg
|   |   cat2.jpg
|   |       …….
|   |_test
|   |   /dog           
|   |   dog1.jpg
|   |   dog2.jpg
|   |       …….
|   |   /cat           
|   |   cat1.jpg
|   |   cat2.jpg
|   |       …….
```

> (369, 169) - number train and test data

I am using flow_from_directory, model.fit_generator.

```
img_rows = 64
img_cols = 64
num_train_samples = 369
num_test_samples = 129
batch_size = 32
epochs = 50

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/data_split/train',
        target_size=(img_rows, img_cols),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/data_split/test',
         target_size=(img_rows, img_cols),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')
```

> Found 736 images belonging to 2 classes. 
>   Found 258 images belonging to 2 classes.

After I trained my model I am doing:

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix

Y_pred = model.predict_generator(validation_generator, num_test_samples // batch_size+1)
y_pred = np.argmax(Y_pred, axis=1)

print('Confusion Matrix')
print(confusion_matrix(validation_generator.classes, y_pred))
print('Classification Report')
target_names = ['Cats', 'Dogs', 'Horse']
print(classification_report(validation_generator.classes, y_pred, target_names=target_names))
```

Now I am getting following error:

> ----> 7 print(confusion_matrix(validation_generator.classes, y_pred))
>   ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of
>   samples: [258, 160]

**validation_generator.classes**

```
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int32)
```

**y_pred**

```
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

**y_pred.shape, validation_generator.classes.shape**

> ((160,), (258,))

What I need to do to solve this issue. I tried to reshape the y_pred it is not working. I hope someone can help me?

Comment: Going by the error, you have validation_generator.classes and y_pred of different sizes. Could you provide what is in these variables before you try to compute confusion_matrix on them.

Comment: Hi Mikhail, I have updated my question. I add the shapes and the numpy array and I hope it helps

Comment: Based on what I found in docs (https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/), you should use `.flow()` method if you want to retrieve all labels. `.classes` attribute is not mentioned as public and shouldn't be used.

Comment: With .flow I can not access the directory.

Comment: Ok, then you can use `flow_from_directory` in the same way. You can iterate over it to get all data. If you want to save space, you can compute `confusion_matrix` for each batch separately and then aggregate them.

Comment: I am not sure if this solves my problem. I have 
((160,), (258,)) y_pred.shape, validation_generator.classes.shape. The error is inconsistent of number. If i integrate throw list then would have same issue